# Can I add date/time to outputted filename in C# file.writeallbytes

Tags: c#, scripting

I am writing an errorlog to to file in the same directory the script exists.  Id like to potentially create a new folder as it writes as well as add date/time to the filenames so they 2nd doesnt save over the first.

Here is what I have so far:

File.WriteAllBytes("ErrorLog.txt")

Thanks!

Comment: It's a little strange to Write All _Bytes_ to a *.txt file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a valid Windows file name with DateTime in it like this:

```
string filename = "ErrorLogFolder" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".txt";
```

Comment: Custom date and time formats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [sample code](http://www.dotnetperls.com/filename-datetime) for naming a file

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Write file containing the date with BIN extension
    //
    string n = string.Format("text-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.bin",
        DateTime.Now);
    File.WriteAllText(n, "aaa");
    }
}
```